# Function generator impedance matching with an amplifier

Tags: amplifier, impedance-matching, signal-generator

I am currently designing an experiment with a material which at low temperatures (below 180K) works like a light detector for infrared. There needs to be a bias applied to the sample which has to be pulsed as it is sensitive to temperature changes. For this we want to use a function generator which is connected to the trigger of the light source (1kHz) so that I am only applying a voltage when the light is shining on the sample. I am using the Tektronix 3022b for that, but when I read through the manual of the Tektronix I found out that the impedances have to match so that the voltages shown on the function generator are the same as the applied voltages. Normally I would say this is no problem as I can just measure the resistance of the object but there a two problems with this:

1. The sample has a non linear IV-curve so the resistance changes with applied voltage and also temperature. Does this mean if I pulse at 50 mV and then at 100 mV do I have to change the impedance with every temperature and voltage step?
2. We also use a transimpedance amplifier from femto (Current Amplifier DLPCA-200) as the currents are very small. Can I just measure the internal resistance of the amplifier and add it to the load? Also this current amplifier can also apply a bias to the circuit which then raises the question of what happens if you have two sources in the setup.

Here is aschematic of the experiment:

[image: Setup]

Comment: It would probably be easier if you stuck to one question and stated what you wanted to happen with the pulse i.e. do you want a fixed amplitude voltage applying to the "thing" or, do you want a fixed amplitude current applying to it. Focus on that.

Comment: Try researching [impedance matching](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/communications/article/21796367/back-to-basics-impedance-matching-part-1) and [transmission lines](http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/AC/AC_14.html) for more information on these subjects.

Comment: Side note, block diagrams and schematics are best drawn with inputs on left and outputs on right; a general "flow" from left to right.  This is because the largest percentage of readers will have learned it this way and expect it.  I suppose this convention could be different in small, select cultures (especially where writing is right-to-left or top-bottom), but the goal with any technical drawing should always be *maximum readability* for *everyone.*